# ImportError: No module named 'project.app'

Tags: python, django

Getting this error whenever I use `python manage.py test`. It fails to import all of my apps. Here's an example:

```
ImportError: No module named 'project.profiles'
```

My project tree is:

```
/project
    /project
    /profiles 
    ...    
    /bin
    /lib
    /include
```

Any idea what the problem is?

EDIT: Here's the traceback (it's the same traceback for each of the 9 apps, I removed 7 of the errors from below to reduce bloat):

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
EEEEEEEEE
======================================================================
ERROR: draft1.advertise (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: draft1.advertise
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 462, in _find_test_path
    package = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 369, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named 'draft1.advertise'


======================================================================
ERROR: draft1.careers (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: draft1.careers
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 462, in _find_test_path
    package = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 369, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named 'draft1.careers'


======================================================================  

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 9 tests in 0.002s

FAILED (errors=9)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Comment: use 'profiles' instead of 'project.profiles'.

Comment: Can you share content of our `project/profiles`? Are you sure that it contain `__init__.py` file?

Comment: @vishes_shell yes it has an `__init__.py` file. It also has a `tests.py` however that is empty. @SadiaArif where do I write that? I didn't write the import statement anywhere.

Comment: Use 'profiles' on your `settings.py` `INSTALLED_APPS` list. I think your base path is referenced to top project folder.

Comment: @DenizKaplan `profiles` is already in my `INSTALLED_APPS`, along with my 8 other apps.  They all fail (all 9 apps get the Import Error).

Comment: Can you share the Traceback error while running this command.

Comment: Can you try to move all apps' folders into inner `project` folder? I guess there is a relative path issue you are experiencing with. If that doesn't help, can you post more detail about your settings file like `BASE_DIR` (where is your `settings.py` file)

Comment: Already tried that and still doesn't work unfortunately. Here's my `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`

Comment: Please expand your project tree. Where is `manage.py`? Where is `settings.py`?

Comment: Here is the more detailed tree: https://i.imgur.com/vgSAgPg.png (`draft1 is my project name`)

Comment: I've added my traceback in my edit (it's the same error for each import) @SadiaArif

Comment: What is your `INSTALLED_APPS`? Try removing the `__init__` from your outer `draft1` directory (the one that contains `manage.py`).

Comment: Ok so I just removed `__init__` from the outer directory and now all the errors are gone. It now says: `Ran 0 tests in 0.000s ... OK` - I assume the tests are now working?

Comment: *Ran 0 tests* doesn’t look good - it didn’t find any of your tests.

Comment: I didn't have any test so I added 1, now getting: `Ran 1 test in 0.003s ... OK` so it's working now. Thanks.